# Odoo: insert image to field.binary()

Tags: javascript, base64, odoo, odoo-9

I need add some image to Odoo.

Image is receiving via javascript:

```
function getBase64(file, callback) {
    var d1 = $.Deferred();
    var result = '';
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        var encoded_file = reader.result;
        callback(btoa(encoded_file));
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        return callback('');
    };
}
```

I have inherit model sale.order:

```
class sale_order(osv.Model):
    _inherit = "sale.order"

    _columns = {
        'attachment_file' : fields.binary(string="Attachment file")
    }
```

In controller present such code(client_attachment is base64 string what received from JS):

```
if (client_attachment!=''):
            sale_value['attachment_file'] = client_attachment
sale_order.write(sale_value)
sale_order.env.cr.commit()
```

In view.xml:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sale_order_webcounter_form_view">
    <field name="name">order.webcounter</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <notebook position="inside">
            <page string="Other information">
                <field name="attachment_file" string="Attachment" widget='image' class="oe_avatar oe_right" />
            </page>
        </notebook>
    </field>
</record>
```

After uploaded file I received error:

> Image
>
> Could not display the selected image.

If i downloaded file from odoo to pc file not displayed.
How I can upload file to odoo?

Comment: What is purpose of `btoa()` call?

Comment: reader.result return string with type file and base64. btoa return only base64 string

Comment: _"reader.result return string with type file and base64. btoa return only base64 string"_ ? `reader.result` is already `base64` encoded `data URI`.